# select elements that doesnt contain a class in multiple class instance

Tags: jquery

Am trying to remove all rows in a table that dont contain a particular class, but each row contains at least 2 classes

```
     <tbody id='orderlist'>
     <tr class='big selected'><td></td></tr>
     <tr class='big'><td></td></tr>
     </tbody>

     $('#orderlist').not('.selected').fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $(this).remove();
     });
```

I want to be able to remove any row that doesnt contain the class selected first by fading it out of view.

Answer (score 2):

Your chained selector for `.not('.selected')` is trying to act upon the elements selected by `$('#orderlist')` (which will be the `tbody` itself), not on the children (the rows).  Try something like this (add `tr` to your `orderlist` selector to get the child rows of your `tbody`):

```
$('#orderlist tr').not('.selected').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WcWex/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and apply conditions to filter out the required set of elements.

```
$('#orderlist tr').filter(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected') && this.className.split(' ').length == 2)
        return $(this);
}).fadeOut('slow').remove();
```

Comment: You are running the filter against the set of elements returned by the `#orderlist` selector which is the `<tbody>`, not the rows within

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#orderlist .big').not('.selected').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.children()`: http://jsfiddle.net/UpHcu/

```
$('#orderlist').children().not('.selected').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    this.remove();
});
```